# MySql restore Backup didn't work

Tags: mysql, xampp

I reinstalled my PC (Windows) but for sure I made a backup of the old data. Now I want to add a database from my old pc so I copyed the folder "C:\xampp\mysql\data\mydatabase" to my new pcs same directory. The database is visible now in my phpmyadmin but I get the message

> Table 'mydatabase.mytable' doesn't exist in Engine

Comment: is there a **CREATE TABLE mytable** in your SQL dump ?

Comment: there are .frm and .ibd files - its not clear text so i can't see if there is create table in it

Comment: You cant copy ibd. Filmes easy. Only Ehen MySQL Version is the Same

Comment: If you use a mysql version >= original version, and you copied the data while the server was not running, you can copy the WHOLE data directory (`\data`, not just a subdirectory) to the new data directory (while the server is not running), overwriting everything. You will lose your current database, so make a real backup this time (with `mysqldump`), and move/copy the whole current data directory (just to be safe and to be able to get back to the current state in case something fails).

Comment: hello ok but i just have the old data i can't get to the old phpmyadmin so what can i do now to restore the old data?

Comment: Noone here is talking about using phpmyadmin. Just copy files in the file system. Before that, you should do a `mysqldump` of your NEW database, because you will loose your current data by overwriting it with your old data-directory.